# Why does redux devtools escape quotes in its JSON exports?

Tags: redux, redux-devtools-extension

Say my application state in redux is this:

```
{ foo: "bar" }
```

When I click 'export' to get a dump of my state, the exported file represents the state like this:

```
{ "preloadedState": "{\"foo\": \"bar\"}" }
```

The escaped quotes (`\"`) are kind of a pain; I can remove them with `sed -i 's/\\"/"/g' state.json` (or with `sed -i '' 's/\\"/"/g' state.json` on macOS), but is there any reason this is the default behaviour, and can I turn it off?

Answer (score 0):

The format is only meant to be used with redux devtools. The value of `preloadedState` here is json data encoded as a string.

To extract the data, you can parse the json string.

```
const data = { "preloadedState": "{\"foo\": \"bar\"}" }
const state = JSON.parse(data.preloadedState)
```